# Check checkbox based on multiple table cell criteria

Tags: javascript, jquery, getelementsbytagname, getelementsbyclassname

I have an html table full of data, the first column contains an input checkbox and a name. I want to check this checkbox when two criteria are met:

1. the name is "Complete"
2. the date sent matches a string passed in "m/d/yyyy" i.e. "9/20/2016" (no leading zeros)

I can already do the first using getElementByTagName("input") and checking if it is a checkbox and that the name is Complete

```
        function checkAllComplete()
        {
            var allRows = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
            for (var i=0; i < allRows.length; i++) {
                if (allRows[i].type == "checkbox" && allRows[i].name == "complete") 
                {
                    allRows[i].checked = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

The date in the cell is "9/20/2016 4:02:03 PM". I also have the regex I want to use to get it into m/d/yyyy:

```
var myRe = new RegExp("^([1-9]|1[012])\/([1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/(19|20)[0-9]{2}", "g");
```

But I'm having trouble getting the corresponding td and it's text. I tried a getElementsByClassName but since there are other input items the counts are off. I tried using class name for the checkboxes but then I cannot check them.

I've assigned a class to all the tds, the first column with the checkbox is "actionClass" and the one with the date string is "dateSentClass"

I'm open to javascript or jquery as a solution.

edit: here's the fiddle with a sample table structure https://jsfiddle.net/trueimage/4u87euz5/2/

Comment: Can you provide an example of your table's structure? A snippet/jsfiddle will be great.

Comment: Selecting by class should get the date. Does that not work? Code would look like `$('.dateSentClass').val()`

Answer (score 0):

To get the checkboxes, you can use:

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
```

or:

```
jQuery('input[type=checkbox]');
```

You can use the following to get an array of the tds:

```
document.querySelectorAll('td.yourClass');
```

and then you can call either `innerHTML` or `textContent` to get the contents of the td as a string.

You can also use:

```
jQuery('td.yourClass');
```

and call `.text()` on each element to get the contents of the td.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to get the text of a `td.dateSentCell` cell that exists in the same row as the cell containing the `input` that is represented by `allRows[i]`. If that's correct, you can use this jQuery:

```
var dateText = $('td.dateSentCell', $(allRows[i]).parent().parent()).text();
```